# How to make a line graph using CorePlot framework and swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, core-plot

I can't understand how to make a line plot with CorePlot 2.2 with Swift 3 (Xcode 8, iOS 10).

Can someone explain how to do it?

Particularly, I don't understand how the last function `numbers` (line 97-103(last lines)) works:

```
    import UIKit
import CorePlot

class dottedLine: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var hostView: CPTGraphHostingView!

    var plot: CPTScatterPlot!


    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        initPlot()
    }



    let xValues: [NSNumber] = [1,2,3,4]
    let yValues: [NSNumber] = [1,5,4,3]

    func initPlot() {
        configureHostView()
        configureGraph()
        configureChart()
        configureAxes()
    }

    func configureHostView() {
        hostView.allowPinchScaling = false
    }

    func configureGraph() {
        // 1 - Create the graph
        let graph = CPTXYGraph(frame: hostView.bounds)
        graph.plotAreaFrame?.masksToBorder = false
        hostView.hostedGraph = graph

        // 2 - Configure the graph
        //graph.apply(CPTTheme(named: CPTThemeName.plainWhiteTheme))
        //graph.fill = CPTFill(color: CPTColor.clear())
        graph.paddingBottom = 30.0
        graph.paddingLeft = 30.0
        graph.paddingTop = 0.0
        graph.paddingRight = 0.0


        // 3 - Set up styles
        let titleStyle = CPTMutableTextStyle()
        titleStyle.color = CPTColor.black()
        titleStyle.fontName = "HelveticaNeue-Bold"
        titleStyle.fontSize = 16.0
        titleStyle.textAlignment = .center
        graph.titleTextStyle = titleStyle

        let title = "Just title"
        graph.title = title
        graph.titlePlotAreaFrameAnchor = .top
        graph.titleDisplacement = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: -16.0)

        // 4 - Set up plot space
        let xMin = 0.0
        let xMax = 5.0
        let yMin = 0.0
        let yMax = 15.0
        guard let plotSpace = graph.defaultPlotSpace as? CPTXYPlotSpace else { return }
        plotSpace.xRange = CPTPlotRange(locationDecimal: CPTDecimalFromDouble(xMin), lengthDecimal: CPTDecimalFromDouble(xMax - xMin))
        plotSpace.yRange = CPTPlotRange(locationDecimal: CPTDecimalFromDouble(yMin), lengthDecimal: CPTDecimalFromDouble(yMax - yMin))
    }

    func configureChart() {
        // 1 - Set up the plot
        plot = CPTScatterPlot()

        // 2 - Set up style
        let plotLineStile = CPTMutableLineStyle()
        plotLineStile.lineWidth = 1
        plotLineStile.lineColor = CPTColor.black()
        plot.dataLineStyle = plotLineStile

        // 3- Add plots to graph
        guard let graph = hostView.hostedGraph else { return }
        plot.dataSource = self
        plot.delegate = self
        graph.add(plot, to: graph.defaultPlotSpace)
    }

    func configureAxes() {
                }
    }



extension dottedLine: CPTScatterPlotDataSource, CPTScatterPlotDelegate {
    func numberOfRecords(for plot: CPTPlot) -> UInt {
        // number of points
        return UInt(xValues.count)
    }

    func scatterPlot(_ plot: CPTScatterPlot, plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecord idx: UInt, with event: UIEvent) {
    }

   /* func numbers(for plot: CPTPlot, field fieldEnum: UInt, recordIndexRange indexRange: NSRange) -> [Any]? {
        print("xxxxxxx")
        switch CPTScatterPlotField(rawValue: Int(fieldEnum))! {
        case .X:
            return xValues[index] as NSNumber

        case .Y:
            return yValues[indexRange] as NSNumber
        }

    } */

   /* func symbols(for plot: CPTScatterPlot, recordIndexRange indexRange: NSRange) -> [CPTPlotSymbol]? {
        return xValues
    } */

    func number(for plot: CPTPlot, field: UInt, record: UInt) -> Any? {


        switch CPTScatterPlotField(rawValue: Int(field))! {
        case .X:
            return 2 as NSNumber

        case .Y:
            return 3 as NSNumber
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a scatter plot, this method will be called once for the x-value and once for the y-value at each index.

Here is that method from the *DatePlot* example app:

```
func number(for plot: CPTPlot, field: UInt, record: UInt) -> Any?
{
    switch CPTScatterPlotField(rawValue: Int(field))! {
    case .X:
        return (oneDay * Double(record)) as NSNumber

    case .Y:
        return self.plotData[Int(record)] as NSNumber
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to insert this function (with changing what it returns) but this function wasn't even called

Comment: Make sure you set the graph's `datasource`.

Comment: Is it a protocol for the class (of view controller)?

Comment: It's a property on the plot. You've implemented the data source protocol in the view controller, so just set it to `self` when configuring the plot.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand how to do this

Comment: You need to create a `CPTScatterPlot`, configure it,  and add it to the graph. Set the `datasource` property on the plot as part of the setup process.

Comment: I have edited my code in the question. For now that function (number(for:...)) works but there is no line in simulator. Axis and numbers on it are visible. What's wrong?

Comment: Made a new post with a new problem. Please, help (I've been trying to do this for 60 hours) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46306033/coreplot-line-chart-line-is-not-visible